# Does flying a plane mid-annual inspection somehow reset the inspection?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, faa

(This question concerns only an airplane which does not have an expired annual.)

Let's say that the IA started an annual, lubed some joints, inspected some parts, and then, for whatever reason, flew the plane before coming back and completing the rest of the annual. Would the IA have to restart from scratch? Or would all actions be considered part of the "annual"?

Does the month in which this happen matter, e.g. IA inspects control linkages on Dec 30th, flies it on Dec 31st, and completes the inspection on Jan 1st?

Looking at https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.409, I can see how the FAA could draw a bright and shining line, saying that any flight at all would imply a progressive maintenance schedule. But does it?

Comment: @RTO In the hypothetical scenario, since the plane is still in annual there would be no violation. My question is whether this action would basically send the inspection back to square 1, i.e. pop off all the covers a second time, reinspect for any ADs, redo a compression test, etc... I've adjusted the question to make this clearer. P.S.: My experience with annuals mirrors yours.

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't know how that would be handled specifically.  I don't believe the regulations address this type issue.

Comment: The only real question I have is whether it would be dated Dec 30th or Jan 1st. An inspection flight in the middle isn't that uncommon. I mean if this was mid-month wouldn't matter due to the rounding to full 12 months and the log signing date would be appropriate. 
Something like this actually happened for my 24-month pilot review, I did the ground in late Dec, did some other flying on the 31st, and finished the flight part of the review on Jan 2nd. It counts as Jan 2nd.